# Wordpress: CSS keeping menu item active when inside child pages

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, submenu

I've been at it for a couple of hours now and still can't figure it out. I want the About Nav Menu link to remain with white background when I'm browsing inside it's child pages...

How do I keep the navlink css active when I'm browsing inside the child page?

[image]
***Viewing page menu item is active***

[image]
***When inside menu item child menu item is no longer active***

[image]

***My CSS***

I've tried almost everything in the wordpress nav reference http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes

Comment: No idea what php you're using, but this will get you some help:

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107398/if-child-is-active-add-class-to-parent-in-customwalker

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you right click on the about tab (when one of the child pages are open,) you should be able to inspect the element.  (I use Chrome, but other browsers have this option.)  You should see something like this.  (This is an example from my theme):

```
<li id="menu-item-387" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page     current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-387"><a href="#">About</a>
```

Choose one of those classes and add some css. I use the 'current-menu-parent' selector.

```
(#menu .current-menu-parent > a {
    background: #fff;   (or whatever styling you need to add)
}
```

Hope this helps.  If not, and your site is accessible from the web, a url would really help.

Comment: You are an angel sent from heaven! :) thank you so much!
I chose: #menu .current-page-ancestor a {...}

Answer (score 0):

When you are on a child page, the Menu Item or Menu Link of the parent page of that active child page has a class `current-page-ancestor`,

you can make your menu active by just adding this to your CSS file or custom CSS

```
li.current-page-ancestor a {
color: #0286ff !important; // or whatever style you want
}
```